# автоматизация запросов API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Добрый день всем кто это читает :)
Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Ситуация следующая:
по API одного из сервисов получаю данные о пользователях. Одним из возможных фильтров к запросам является фильтр дат создания пользователя.

"created_at[from]=YYYY-MM-DD
created_at[to]=YYYY-MM-DD"

как мне автоматизировать запрос данных от сервиса на текущий день? (чтобы каждый новый день мой скрипт в 18:00 получал данные от сервиса самостоятельно, без моего вмешательства)

Comment: А как сейчас получаете, каким-то python скриптом или еще как-то?

Comment: Запускать планируете под Linux или Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вызова кода в определенные дни/время удобно использовать библиотеку `schedule` (`pip install schedule`)

```
import time
import schedule

def run():
    print('Запуск')
    # Добавите запрос в API

# Каждый день в 18:00
schedule.every().day.at("18:00").do(run)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

А для получения текущей даты используйте модуль `datetime` с форматирование даты в строку по шаблону:

```
import datetime as DT

today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# Или: today_str = f'{DT.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}'
query = f"created_at[from]={today_str} created_at[to]={today_str}"
print(query)
# created_at[from]=2021-07-26 created_at[to]=2021-07-26
```

Comment: А как сделать автоматически запрос на новую дату? Чтобы сегодня он запросил данные на 26 число, завтра на 27 и т.д. без моих правок в коде

Comment: @Vadim, добавил пример

Comment: к сожалению пример вызова кода выдает ошибку. Скорее всего я не заметил какую-то важную деталь. Не могли бы Вы подсказать? 
Вот мой код:
```
import requests 
import datetime as DT
import schedule

def run():
    print('Запуск')
    today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    query = f"created_at[from]={today_str}, created_at[to]={today_str}"
    params = {'key' : '5D6',
              'created_at[from]': today_str,
              'created_at[to]': today_str}
    response = requests.get ("https://100.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users?", params = params)
   ```

Comment: ```
result = response.json()
    print (result)

schedule.every().day.at("18:00").do(run)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: выдает такую ошибку name 'time' is not defined

Comment: Импортируйте модуль `time`, `import time`

Answer (score 0):

Если используете Linux, то можно использовать встроенный в него планировщик заданий `Cron`, для которого можно выставлять задания, которые будут выполняться даже в случае перезагрузки сервера.

Для Python есть библиотека, упрощающая работу с заданиями в нем, [`python-crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/). Вариант делать задание каждую минуту:

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)
job = cron.new(command='python /home/user/stackoverflow/make_write.py')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```

Если нужно делать по времени в 18:00, то меняем `job.minute.every(1`) на `job.setall(time(18, 0))` и добавляем в файл `from datetime import time`

```
from datetime import time    
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)
job = cron.new(command='python /home/user/stackoverflow/make_write.py')
job.setall(time(18, 0))

cron.write()
```

Файл make_write.py:

```
with open('/home/user/stackoverflow/text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('Hello')
```

Вывести все имеющиеся задания:

```
cron = CronTab(user=True)
for job in cron:
    print(job)
```

Удалить все задания:

```
cron.remove_all()
```